# opencv threshold operation limited to 8-bit types and 32-bit floats

Tags: opencv

I tried to threshold a CV_32S, grayscale image. Lo and behold the operation fails. After a more careful reading of the docs I noticed:

> src = input array (single-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit floating point) ...

Why the limitation to these types only?

Comment: Because this operations are highly optimized only some types (the ones you actually would use). In your case, you can just do: `Mat1b thresholded = my_img > some_value;`

Comment: I'll take that if you care to answer the question.